# Performant PipeWriter?

Tags: c#, .net-core

I have written a json byte serializer using standard byte arrays etc and that works fine. For comparison, I attempted a pipewriter implementation using what little information I could find on System.IO.Pipelines.

Its unreasonably slow, this might be due to  my limited experience with it or maybe its not meant for this use case. I would appreciate some help understanding why this is so slow and if its not supposed to be slow, where I am going wrong.

**I am targeting NetStandard 2.0 and NetCore 2.1 so don't have access to Encoding.ASCII span overloads.**

Sample repo at https://github.com/benardmens/PipelinePerf

or for the one pager aficionados code below

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Converters;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization;
using NodaTime;
using NodaTime.Serialization.JsonNet;
using System;
using System.Buffers;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.Immutable;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.Compression;
using System.IO.Pipelines;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace OnePage
{
    #region support
    internal static class ConverterCache
    {
        #region variables

        #endregion

        #region properties
        internal static Dictionary<Type, JsonConverter> Converters { get; }
        internal static List<JsonConverter> CreationConverters { get; }
        #endregion

        #region construction
        static ConverterCache()
        {
            var types = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(ConverterCache)).GetTypes();
            Converters = new Dictionary<Type, JsonConverter>();
            var converterTypes = types.
                Where(x => !x.IsAbstract && !x.IsInterface && typeof(IConverterDescriptor).IsAssignableFrom(x)).
                ToArray();

            foreach (var converterDescriptor in converterTypes.Select(x => Activator.CreateInstance(x) as IConverterDescriptor).Where(x => x != null))
            {
                Converters[converterDescriptor.TypeToConvert] = converterDescriptor as JsonConverter;
            }

            CreationConverters = types.
                Where(x => typeof(JsonConverter).
                IsAssignableFrom(x)).
                Where(x => x.BaseType != null && x.BaseType.IsGenericType && x.BaseType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(CustomCreationConverter<>)).
                Select(x => Activator.CreateInstance(x) as JsonConverter).
                ToList();
        }
        #endregion

        #region methods

        #endregion

        #region event methods

        #endregion

        #region overrides

        #endregion
    }

    public interface IConverterDescriptor
    {
        #region variables

        #endregion

        #region properties
        Type TypeToConvert { get; }
        #endregion

        #region construction

        #endregion

        #region methods

        #endregion

        #region event methods

        #endregion

        #region overrides

        #endregion
    }

    public class IpCreationConverter : CustomCreationConverter<IPAddress>
    {
        #region variables

        #endregion

        #region properties

        #endregion

        #region construction

        #endregion

        #region methods

        #endregion

        #region event methods

        #endregion

        #region overrides
        public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
        {
            var retVal = objectType == typeof(IPAddress);
            if (retVal)
                return true;
            return objectType == typeof(IPAddress);
        }

        public override IPAddress Create(Type objectType)
        {
            return IPAddress.Parse("0.0.0.0");
        }
        #endregion
    }

    public class IpEndPointCreationConverter : CustomCreationConverter<IPEndPoint>
    {
        #region variables

        #endregion

        #region properties

        #endregion

        #region construction

        #endregion

        #region methods

        #endregion

        #region event methods

        #endregion

        #region overrides
        public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
        {
            var retVal = objectType == typeof(IPEndPoint);
            if (retVal)
                return true;
            return objectType == typeof(IPEndPoint);
        }

        public override IPEndPoint Create(Type objectType)
        {
            return new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("0.0.0.0"), 0);
        }
        #endregion
    }

    public interface IRecordDataSerializer
    {
        Task<bool> Serialize(object record, PipeWriter writer);
        Task<bool> SerializeCompressed(object record, PipeWriter writer);
    }

    public class ObjectToJsonRecordSerializer : IRecordDataSerializer
    {
        public async Task<bool> Serialize(object record, PipeWriter writer)
        {
            try
            {
                var bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Serializer.Serialize(record, Formatting.None));
                var sizeBytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(bytes.Length);
                await writer.WriteAndAdvance(sizeBytes);

                await writer.WriteAndAdvance(bytes);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }

        private readonly ArrayPool<byte> _arrayPool = ArrayPool<byte>.Shared;
        private byte[] _rented;
        public async Task<bool> SerializeCompressed(object record, PipeWriter writer)
        {
            try
            {
                var data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Serializer.Serialize(record, Formatting.None));
                _rented = _arrayPool.Rent(data.Length * 2);

                using (var compressedStream = new MemoryStream(_rented))
                using (var zipStream = new GZipStream(compressedStream, CompressionMode.Compress))
                {
                    zipStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);


                    var sizeBytes = BitConverter.GetBytes((int)compressedStream.Position);
                    await writer.WriteAndAdvance(sizeBytes);

                    //get the slice of the stream actually written to and persist
                    Memory<byte> memSlice = _rented;
                    await writer.WriteAndAdvance(memSlice.Slice(0, (int)compressedStream.Position));
                    _arrayPool.Return(_rented);
                    zipStream.Close();
                }

            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                _arrayPool.Return(_rented);
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
    }

    public class Record
    {
        public Record(Instant recordTime, IEnumerable<RecordEntry> entries)
        {
            Entries = entries.ToImmutableList();
            RecordTime = recordTime;
        }

        public Record()
        {

        }

        public ImmutableList<RecordEntry> Entries { get; set; }

        public Instant RecordTime { get; set; }

    }

    public class RecordEntry
    {
        public RecordEntry(object value)
        {
            Value = value;
        }

        public RecordEntry()
        {
        }


        public object Value { get; set; }
    }

    public class Resolver : DefaultContractResolver
    {
        #region variables

        #endregion

        #region properties

        #endregion

        #region construction

        #endregion

        #region methods
        protected override JsonContract CreateContract(Type objectType)
        {
            var contract = base.CreateContract(objectType);
            if (ConverterCache.Converters.TryGetValue(objectType, out JsonConverter converter))
                contract.Converter = converter;

            return contract;
        }

        protected override IList<JsonProperty> CreateProperties(Type type, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
        {
            //return base.CreateProperties(type, memberSerialization).ToList();
            return base.CreateProperties(type, memberSerialization).Where(p => p.Writable).ToList();
        }
        #endregion

        #region event methods

        #endregion

        #region overrides

        #endregion
    }

    public static class Serializer
    {
        #region variables

        private static readonly JsonSerializerSettings Settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto,
            ObjectCreationHandling = ObjectCreationHandling.Replace,
            ContractResolver = new Resolver(),
            Converters = ConverterCache.CreationConverters,
            DateFormatHandling = DateFormatHandling.IsoDateFormat,
            DateTimeZoneHandling = DateTimeZoneHandling.Utc,
        };

        #endregion

        #region properties

        #endregion

        #region construction

        static Serializer()
        {
            Settings.ConfigureForNodaTime(DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb);
        }

        #endregion

        #region methods

        /// <summary>
        /// Deserializes a json string into the specified type
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
        /// <param name="content"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static T Deserialize<T>(string content)
        {
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(content, Settings);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Serializes object into a json string
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="subject"></param>
        /// <param name="formatting"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static string Serialize(object subject, Formatting formatting = Formatting.Indented)
        {
            return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(subject, formatting, Settings);
        }

        #endregion

        #region event methods

        #endregion

        #region overrides

        #endregion
    }
    #endregion
    public static class PipeWriterExtensions
    {
        public static async Task WriteAndAdvance(this PipeWriter writer, byte[] data)
        {
            await writer.WriteAsync(data);
        }

        public static async Task WriteAndAdvance(this PipeWriter writer, Memory<byte> data)
        {
            await writer.WriteAsync(data);
        }
    }
    public class AsyncToBinaryConverter
    {
        private readonly string[] _headers;
        public event Action<PipeReader> OnBytes;
        private readonly Pipe _pipe = new Pipe();
        private bool _infoWritten;
        private readonly IRecordDataSerializer _serializer;
        private readonly object[] _array = new object[1];
        private PipeWriter _writer;

        public AsyncToBinaryConverter(IEnumerable<string> headers, IRecordDataSerializer serializer)
        {
            _serializer = serializer;
            _headers = headers.ToArray();
        }


        public Task<bool> WriteAsync(object subject)
        {
            _array[0] = subject;
            return Write(_array);
        }

        public async Task<bool> Write<TSubjectType>(IEnumerable<TSubjectType> subjects)
        {
            _pipe.Writer.Complete();
            _pipe.Reader.Complete();
            _pipe.Reset();
            //if any fails we cannot output
            _writer = _pipe.Writer;
            foreach (var subject in subjects)
            {
                var success = await Convert(subject);
                if (!success) return false;
            }
            await _writer.FlushAsync();

            //process and output the buffer
            OnBytes?.Invoke(_pipe.Reader);
            return true;
        }



        private async Task<bool> Convert(object subject)
        {

            try
            {
                //only write the type and headers once
                if (!_infoWritten)
                {
                    var result = await AddInfoBytes(subject.GetType(), _writer);
                    if (!result)
                    {
                        return false;
                    }
                    _infoWritten = true;
                }

                //serialize and compress the sample
                await _serializer.SerializeCompressed(subject, _writer);

                return true;
            }
            catch
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        private async Task<bool> AddInfoBytes(Type subjectType, PipeWriter writer)
        {

            try
            {
                //get the string that's useable by Type.GetType

                var typeString = $"{subjectType.AssemblyQualifiedName}";
                var bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(typeString);
                var contentLength = bytes.Length;
                var sizeBytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(contentLength);
                //write the size...
                await writer.WriteAndAdvance(sizeBytes);

                //and the contents
                await writer.WriteAndAdvance(bytes);

                //write the header bytes
                await _serializer.Serialize(_headers, writer);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

and the test

```
   [TestMethod]
    public void Poc()
    {
        var random = new Random();
        var writer = new AsyncToBinaryConverter(new[] { "", "as", "asdsa" }, new ObjectToJsonRecordSerializer());
        // var reader = new FromBinaryConverter();
        var count = 0;
        writer.OnBytes += x =>
        {

            var m = x;
        };
        //   reader.OnObject += x => count++;
        var record = new Record(SystemClock.Instance.GetCurrentInstant(), Enumerable.Range(1, 50).Select(x => new RecordEntry(random.NextDouble())));
        var records = Enumerable.Range(1, 10000).Select(x => record);
        var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        writer.Write(records).Wait();
        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);

        //Assert.AreEqual(10000, count);
    }
```

Thanks for reading

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but JSON should really be utf8 encoded with no BOM. https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7159#section-8.1 for performance, have you tried profiling it in detail? There is some overhead in `async`/`await` so lots of small calls can be expensive. The first time you run it, it will have to JIT of course too, so ignore it when profiling.

Comment: @GeorgeHelyar, thanks for the comment, noted, I would try profiling but I found out today when the issue first occured, that profiling .net core is not supported by visual studio!! How crazy is that?

Comment: Does your use case support buffering a block of data (storing to the buffer can be a synchronous operation) and then one large asynchronous write sending the whole block?  I would recommend block transfers if you can.

Comment: A link to your ready-to-build repo is nice, but it is not a substitute for the code.  Have both :)